# Mapping dictionary of tuples to DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, tuples

When mapping a dictionary of tuples to a DataFrame the mapping results in NaN value

```
dfTemp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Lokaal','LocalX','LocalY', 'test'])
dfTemp['LocalX'] = pd.Series([22, 32])
dfTemp['LocalY'] = pd.Series([40, 50])
dfTemp['Lokaal'] = pd.Series([lab1, lab2])


dict = {"lab1":(337, 50, 230, 275),
           "lab2":(337, 315, 230, 320)
          }

dfTemp["test"] = dfTemp["Lokaal"].map(dict)




expected result:

LocalX LocalY Lokaal test
22     40     lab1   (337,50,230,275)
32     50     lab2   (337, 315, 230, 320)

actual result:

LocalX LocalY Lokaal test
22     40     lab1   NaN
32     50     lab2   NaN
```

No error message is given.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Works fine here.

Comment: @rafaelc the pd.Series([lab1, lab2]) should be pd.Series(["lab1", "lab2"]). Sorry my bad

Comment: I know. Still should work

Comment: @rafaelc indeed, it should. But it does not :(

Comment: I confirm that it works fine in Python 3.7 with pandas 0.25.0